# Is there a number of tables in Slick that hurts badly the performance of Scala-Compiler?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, slick

Context:

I am developing a software in Scala and for the database part I'm using Slick. Currently I'm working with Slick 3.0 and Scala 2.11.7 using IntelliJ 15.0 as IDE and PostgreSQL as DB

Problem:

I have run into a worrisome problem with Scala phase typer. So the thing is that I have multiple big tables (50+ columns), and I was refactoring them into multiple tables, making some relationships. But for whatever reason the compiler started to get stuck in "phase typer" in one of those big tables.

I deleted some tables and suddenly, the compiler makes his way through the phase typer again. (I don't have even a big number of tables <40 for sure)

So that's why I am asking, if there is a number of tables that hurt the performance of the scala compiler, or if maybe I am missing something.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Often when one entity (object, class, trait) needs compilation and it resides in the same source as other entities, scalac will compile everything in the same file. I've seen that cause compilation chain reactions that were easily fixed by separating some of the entities in its own files.